# how to write regex of this type for us canada and australia zip codes

Tags: regex

I have following regex which test for US and Canada zip codes,

```
(\d{5})(-\d{4})?$|^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$
```

what should i add to it so that it will check for australian zip codes as well

Comment: If you imply that we know all zip code formats used in 200 countries, you are completely wrong. Show us sample(s).

Comment: 1. Explain current regex, maybe explode it. 2. provide the australian zip code specifications

Comment: http://www.pixelenvision.com/1708/zip-postal-code-validation-regex-php-code-for-12-countries/

Comment: Sorry i m newbie to this but this form itself is not known to me :-(

Comment: @Andrew Logvinov people usually asks question and help when they try many things and then get stuck...:-|   But i cant write down all the things i have tried so far...so noted down only working regex here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just 4 digits in Australia so add `|\\d{4}` to regex.
And for the future, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes) is list of zip code formats for variety of countries